# Работа с большим количеством записей в db

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 3000 Логинов в бд. С каждым Логинов я должен отправить запрос к серверу через прокси (всегда разные). Пытался при помощи while доставать в цикле  и потом через курл с прокси отправлять запросы. Но возникал лимит времени ну или попадалась мертвая прокси и все почему то останавливалось. Вопрос: как достать из бд большое количество данных и сделать запросы со всеми данными, через прокси?

Comment: что этот вопрос вообще значит ? школа юных хакеров в соседнем здании.

Comment: Да как угодно. Главное чтобы отправились все 1000 запросов.

Comment: > Вопрос: как достать из бд большое количество данных и сделать запросы со всеми данными, через прокси?

1. Сделать failsafe-приложение, которое нормально реагирует на подвисшую проксю.
2. Запускать из консоли.

Comment: Поподробнее можно?

Comment: @Vlmake

конечно

1. Сделать механизм запуска запросов через проксю таким, чтобы он ловил ошибки / корректно отрабатывал ошибочные результаты и переходил к следующей прокси из пула, вываливая критическую ошибку только в том случае, если он попробовал все прокси подряд и ни одна не сработала.
2. Запускать из консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу можно решить очень простым способом:

```
ignore_user_abort(1);  // Игнорировать обрыв связи с браузером
set_time_limit(0);       // Время работы скрипта неограниченно

while(/** Условия **/)
{
  //Ваш цикл
}
```

А насчет мертвой прокcи, сделайте проверку. Если запрос прошел неудачно, берем новый прокси и отправляем заново.

Вы можете запустить скрипт и закрыть страницу. А для оповещения о завершении можно в конце всего скрипта поставить отправку оповещения вам на email или создать файл на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Если работа из консоли

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Запустил и смотри результат выполнения ))

Comment: Как вариант, в БД добавить поле для чека, обработана строка иль нет.
Для того чтоб при перезапуске старые строки не обрабатывать.

Comment: @Алексей Дорохов

http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php

> max_execution_time integer
Эта директива задает максимальное время в секундах ... Если PHP запущен из командной строки, это значение по умолчанию равно 0.

Вероятность того, что там сидит хостер, который режет консольные скрипты по времени, примерно настолько же мала, как то, что автор запускает скрипт из консоли, только в квадрате.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам так хочется асинхронно слать запросы, да еще и с помощью PHP, да еще и через веб-морду, я бы посоветовал на веб-страничку цепануть не большой JS скрипт, который будет слать AJAX запрос к вашему php отсыльщику 1 запрос - 1 адрес. И будет вам "псевдо" асинхронная работа, да еще и статус можно отследить без особых проблем.

Увидел в теме что-то о прокси... Если вам не сложно: [user.hashcode.ru/questions/7479/](http://user.hashcode.ru/questions/7479/web-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Буду рад помочь вам с реализацией вашего приложения, если вы поможете мне с моей статистикой :)

Comment: Я беру на hideme

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно выставить `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30)` - таймаут для curl в секундах, если прокся отвалится, тогда курл возвратит ошибку и вы сможете запустить серез другую проксю. Кроме того, обрабатывать данные лучше порциями либо через ajax, как предложили выше, либо получать, например, 100 записей, записывать в табличку рядом id последней, и через заголовок редиректа ("Location:") перезагружать страницу, либо id последней посылать в get заголовка.

Comment: Но я запускаю скрипт через cron каждые 10 минут.